# Custom Query for Taxonomy

Tags: customization, taxonomy, query

What is the correct wpdb custom query for this:

```
taxonomy=pa_main-genre&post_type=product&orderby=name&order=asc
```

Basically i am trying to do is,list all the terms for pa_main-genre. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of the terms, use get_terms():

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms('pa_main-genre', array('orderby' => name,));
?>
```

Comment: How about using wpdb class? Like <?php $wpdb->get_results('query', OBJECT_K); ?>

Comment: @johndavedecano what would be the reason to use `$wpdb`? Does `get_terms()` not return what you need? If so, then I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: I think there is something overriding that function. So i need to use a custom sql query to retrieve the taxonomies terms